# How do I write a nested loop into a file in file explorer

Tags: java, loops, nested

I need to write into a .txt file using `print()` and `println()`. I am stuck.
Can someone show me how it's done?

```java
package lesson6;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class DataWriter {

    private static PrintWriter output;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("data.txt");

        try {

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);

            System.out.println("file not found");

            System.out.println("Writing to file");

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

                for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {

                    int product = i * j;

                    System.out.print(i + "x" + j + "=" + product + " ");

                }

                System.out.println();

            }

        } finally {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Check [how to write to a file in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file).

Comment: You can use `output.print` and `output.println()` instead of `System.out`. `PrintWriter` is also an `OutputStream`

Comment: When approaching problems like this, you should break them up into smaller chunks. Loops and file explorer (whatever that is) have nothing to do with ability to write to files. Figure out how to write a simple string into a file, then apply it to your bigger problem.

Comment: As the others have hinted, this is not what `System.out.println` was created for.

Comment: I know I have written to a file before I am just lost on how to do it with nested loops I have already tried removing it and replacing it but its still not writing to my file